# Equality on complex functions with complex type

Tags: coq

I want to prove following lemma.

```
Require Import CoLoR.Util.Vector.VecUtil.
Require Import Coq.Vectors.Vector.
From mathcomp Require Import ssreflect.

Lemma Vcast_func' (A:Type):
forall (n m l:nat)(v:t A (n+0))(eq:n+0=m+0)
       (func1:t A (n+0) -> t A l)(func2:t A (m+0) -> t A l)
       (foo: forall {n l:nat}, (t A (n+0) -> t A l) -> t A (n+0) -> t A (n+0)),
       Equiv func1 func2 eq -> Vcast (foo func1 v) eq = foo func2 (Vcast v eq).
Proof.
move=> n m l v eq.
Abort.
```

I want to use the solutions according to [Equality on complex functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64465720/equality-on-complex-functions).

But, I can't do `case: m / eq` because `m` doesn't be inferred `m+0` as it is. Also, I can't rewrite `n+0=m+0` to `n=m` because `n+0=m+0` is used in a hypothesis.

Are there any solutions?

Comment: Your question is not self-contained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
Require Import CoLoR.Util.Vector.VecUtil.
Require Import Coq.Vectors.Vector.
From mathcomp Require Import ssreflect.
Require Import Coq.Logic.FunctionalExtensionality.
Require Import Coq.Logic.Eqdep_dec.

Definition Equiv {A n m l}(I:t A n -> t A l)(J:t A m -> t A l)(eq:n=m):Prop:=
    forall (a : t A n), I a = J (Vcast a eq) .

Lemma Vcast_func (A:Type):
forall (n m l:nat)(v:t A (n+0))(eq:n+0=m+0)
       (func1:t A (n+0) -> t A l)(func2:t A (m+0) -> t A l)
       (foo: forall {n l:nat}, (t A (n+0) -> t A l) -> t A (n+0) -> t A (n+0)),
       Equiv func1 func2 eq -> Vcast (foo func1 v) eq = foo func2 (Vcast v eq).
Proof.
move=> n m l v e.
have e' : n = m by rewrite -{1}(plus_n_O n) -{1}(plus_n_O m) in e.
rewrite -{}e' in e * => func1 func2 foo.
rewrite (UIP_refl_nat _ e) /= => {}e.
suff -> : func1 = func2 by [].
apply: functional_extensionality=> {}v.
exact: e.
Qed.
```

In more detail:

1. Since `n + 0 = m + 0`, we know that `n = m`. This is what the `have` tactic is doing.
2. Thus, we can replace `m` by `n` everywhere.
3. Finally, we argue that `e : n + 0 = n + 0` must be equal to `eq_refl`, thanks to the `UIP_refl_nat` lemma.

Comment: in my version of Coq `UIP_refl_nat` does not exist, it can be replaced with `UIP_refl nat`.  ARe you sure there is not a typo in your answer.

Comment: @Yves I think I had the wrong import earlier (`ProofIrrelevance` instead of `Eqdep_dec`). It is fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

The hypothesis `eq` can't be modified, but you can make a copy that will be used in the goal instead.

```
move:(eq)=> eq'.
```

Then, `eq` is not used in the goal anymore, only the copy `eq'`.

Comment: This syntax is the ssreflect version of `generalize` tactic.